# Redirect root to subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to use "www.domain.com/public" as "www.domain.com" and deny access to all the remaining directories in "public_html/".
Currently i have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public [L]
```

This works just fine but I need it to be domain agnostic because it's for a framework that will run on several domains.

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: so why not redefine your site's document root to to be `/a/b/c/site/public` instead of `/a/b/c/d/site`?

Comment: because it is supposed to be server and domain agnostic i want it to work out of the box on most servers with any domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much researching i came up with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Works like a charm plus i added routing.
I can move the folder that contains the .htaccess arround and it will still work.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is set it up so that "blog" or "public" (your question uses two different subfolders) or whatever to be your document root.

If you don't have access to your server's config files, then you can try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 ^blog/
RewriteRUle ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank's. I tried it but with no success. The only diference is that now "www.domain.com/public" gives me a 404 and "www.domain.com" still shows the project directories.